# Plot network with minimum overlap

Tags: plot

Not sure this is the right place to ask. I want to draw the scheme of a network (in fact, different genotypes connected by their possible mutations) with minimum overlap. I want something fast and easy to use, as I will not redo this image several times.

I remember, some years ago, using some free software were I just had to draw nodes and edged between them, and them select rearrange :) Can any of you remember anything like that? Or have a suggestion for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up finding the program I remember. If anyone is interested, it was [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). There might be better ones out there, but this worked for me :)